# How can TSP be an NP-optimization problem, when a feasible solution $s$ must be polynomial bounded in the instance size $|I|$?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np, traveling-salesman

How can TSP be an NP-optimization problem ?

The definition of an NP-optimization problem $\Pi$ states that for each instance $I \in \Pi$ , the set of feasible solutions $S_\Pi(I)$ is non-empty and that the size of each $s \in S_\Pi(I)$ is polynomial bounded in $|I|$, where $|I|$ denote the size of $I$.

However, in the case of TSP an instance will be encoded using $n^2$ bits, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the instance graph, using the adjacency matrix representation.

But there are $n!$ feasible solutions ? In order to encode these one must use $n! \setminus 2^n$ bits. This number increase as $n$ increase, but $p(|I|)$ is fixed ?

How I overseen something ?

Comment: *"The size of **each** $s \in S_{\Pi}(I)$ is polynomially bounded"*, not the number of solutions.

Comment: But how should I encode $s$ so that I can represent each feasible solution using $p(|I|)$ bits ? Since there are $n!$ possibilities for $s$, I need to use at least $n! \setminus 2^n$ bits, right ?

Comment: I noticed that detail in the question and I was about to answer. A solution in the TSP problem is a sequence of vertices, right? How many bits do you need for that?

Comment: There are $n!$ sequences, so I need to use at least $n! \setminus 2^n$ bits ?

Comment: You need $n \log n $ bits to encode all permutations of vertices: $n$ vertices each labeled with $\log{n}$ bits. This indeed grows with $n$. What exactly is the size of the instance $I$?

Comment: The size of the instance is $n^2$, right ? Why do I only need $n$ permutations ?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed a typo. I meant all permutations. Each vertex has a label (1 to $n$). Hence, you need $\log{n}$ bits to encode each label. Now, to describe any sequence of $n$ vertices, you need to concatenate the $n$ labels. So $n\log{n}$ bits in total.

Comment: Ahh, that's a smart way to do it ! Isn't it right that $n! \setminus 2^n$ bits could also do the job ? Does this fraction equal $n \log n$ also ?

Comment: You could always find an unnecessarily expensive way to describe a solution. But that does not meed you "need" it!

Comment: Maybe I am underestimating the level of your issue, but I think you may profit from reading [our reference material](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/845/98).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in the TSP problem is a sequence of $n$ vertices. 
Consider a labeling $1,\dots, n$ of the $n$ vertices. 
We need $O(\log{n})$ bits to encode the label of each vertex. 
Then, any sequence of $n$ vertices can be described by $O(n\log{n})$ bits; the concatenation of $n$ vertex labels. 
Hence, any solution $s$ of the TSP can be described by a number of bits that is polynomial in $n$.

The size of the instance $I$ is also polynomial in the number of vertices $n$, as noted in the original question.